# Как правильно написать? Я — сама «Мисс Удача» или Я сама «Мисс Удача»

Tags: пунктуация, орфография, тире

Смысл кавычек — в самоиронии человека-неудачника.

Answer (score 1):

*Я — сама «Мисс Удача»*

Конечно, предпочтительнее вариант с тире:

В данном случае тире нужно для внесения ясности в предложение: если тире убрать, будет не вполне ясно к какому члену предложения относится слово *сама* — к сказуемому *«Мисс Удача»* (как вы и задумывали) или к подлежащему *Я*. Так, при отсутствии тире смысл предложения может быть воспринят следующим образом:

> *Я сама — «Мисс Удача» (Видишь, ты не один такой, так что не беспокойся, что тебе иногда не везёт.)*

Итак, без тире смысл этого предложения может быть понят по-разному. А оно Вам надо? Думаю, нет.

Таким образом, тире в Вашем примере **ставится**!

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от контекста и постановки логических ударений.

Оценка очередного эпизода

1. *Этого следовало ожидАть, **я сама «мисс УдАча»**.*
2. *Что тут можно **о себе** сказать? **Я – сама «мисс Удача»**.*

Во втором варианте местоимение ***я*** перед паузой выделено логическим ударением, а такое выделение подходит не для каждой фразы.

Что касается  понимания: я сама/«мисс Удача», то в данном **контексте** оно исключено по смыслу.